# How to solve "Element type is invalid" Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a Twitter clone using react but I'm facing the following error.

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `SidebarOption`.**

Here is my code:-

*app.js*

```
import "./styles.css";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Sidebar.js*

```
import React from "react";
import SidebarOption from "./SidebarOption";
import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import ExploreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Explore";
import NotificationsActiveIcon from "@material-ui/icons/NotificationsActive";
import EmailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Email";
import BookmarksIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Bookmarks";
import ListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/List";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import MoreHorizIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon} text="Home" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={ExploreIcon} text="Explore" />
      <SidebarOption text="Notifications" />
      <SidebarOption text="Message" />
      <SidebarOption text="Bookmarks" />
      <SidebarOption text="List" />
      <SidebarOption text="Profile" />
      <SidebarOption text="More..." />
      <SidebarOption text="Tweet" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

*SidebarOption.js*

```
function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon />
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

Comment: What is the `<Icon />` / `ExploreIcon`, if it's passed in as a component surely you'd need `{ Icon }` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass your Icon component and use like this

```
  <SidebarOption Icon={<ExploreIcon></ExploreIcon>} text="Explore" />
```

```
function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div>
       {Icon}
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! but why cant I pass it as a Component ? eg. <Icon />

Comment: @Vrushabh Fasge you can. You would need an additional check inside `SidebarOption` for it to only render when `Icon` isn't undefined.

Comment: @VrushabhFasge Yup. you can do it too.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the `Icon` prop to the below ones but you're expecting to render it inside `SidebarOption`. You can add an additional check for whether `Icon` is undefined or not and based on it render the same inside `SidebarOption`. :-

```
      <SidebarOption text="Home" /><HomeIcon/>
      <SidebarOption text="Notifications" />
      <SidebarOption text="Message" />
      <SidebarOption text="Bookmarks" />
      <SidebarOption text="List" />
      <SidebarOption text="Profile" />
      <SidebarOption text="More..." />
      <SidebarOption text="Tweet" />
```

**Edit** - The answer by @Vo Quoc Thang should also work because their even if you don't pass `Icon` prop, you're not declaring it as a component in your `SidebarOption` but just a normal prop. For `Icon` value being `undefined`, it simply won't render.

Comment: Yup. I was misunderstood at first. This solution works too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if Icon is defined before using it:

```
import React from "react";

function SidebarOption({ text, Icon }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Icon && <Icon />}
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarOption;
```